# $R$ integral domain : $u\in R^*, a \text{ is prime} \iff au \text{ is prime}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers

> $R$ integral domain : $u\in R^*,\; a \text{ is prime} \iff au \text{ is prime}$

I started by looking at $auu^{-1}$. What should I do next?
I'd be glad for help.

Note: $u \in R^*$ meaning is $u$ is invertible.

Comment: Show $a \mid b \iff (au) \mid b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $au\mid bc$. Then, there exists $k$ such that $auk=bc$. Therefore, $a\mid bc$. Since $a$ is prime, $a$ divides $b$ or $c$. Then, $au$ divides $bu$ or $cu$.

If $au$ divides $bu$ then $auj=bu$ for some $j$, and $auju^-1=b$; thus, $au\mid b$.

A similar reasoning gives that if $au$ divides $cu$ then $au$ divides $c$.

We supposed that $au\mid bc$ and we have concluded that $au$ divides $b$ or $c$. Therefore, $au$ is prime.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. Can you help me with the other direction please?

Comment: Lets assume $a|bc$ then $au|bcu$. Since $au$ is a prime $au|b$ or $au|c$ or $au|u (?)

Comment: Correction: $au|bcu \implies au|bu \lor au|cu \implies a|b \lor a|c$. Therefore, $a$ is a prime.

Answer (score 1):

$$a\;\;\text{is prime}\;\;\iff\;\; aR=\langle a\rangle\;\;\text{is a prime ideal}$$

and the claim follows at once observing that $\;\langle a\rangle = \langle au \rangle\;$

Comment: What is a prime ideal? Can you please rephrase it without this term? We learned in class that $a$ is prime iff $a|xy \implies a|x$ or $a|y$.

Comment: Yes. An ideal $\;I\;$ in a ring $\;R\;$ is prime iff $$\;rs\in I\implies r\in I\;\;or\;\;s\in I\;$$ Observe this means **exactly** the same as your definition when the ideal is principal, i.e.: if $\;I=pR=\langle p\rangle\;$ , then $\;I\;$ is prime iff $\;p\;$ is prime